# What would be the correct markup in this situation (page title and "rootline")?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

So, in my current project, when you navigate to the "team" page, which has the path `/home/about/company/team/` the header of the page looks like this:

```
/home/about/company/    <--- this is what i call the "rootline"
TEAM                    <-- this is the title of the current page

... content goes here ...
```

My current markup looks like this:

```
<h1>TEAM</h1>
<h2>/home/about/company/</h2>

<div id="content"> 
    <h3>Content Headline</h3>
    ... 
</div>
```

But it feels wrong to wrap the rootline in `h2` tags. Actually, its not a headline, right? Whats your opinion on how to create good, semantic HTML in this case?

Comment: So the *rootline* is just indicating where you are in hierarchy? I think there is no special markup for this.

Comment: I don't think I would use any heading tag on the "rootline" but only because of SEO implications. Other than that, I don't think there is any other issues.

Comment: What does SEO have to do with it?  The use of header tags is not the exclusive purview of search marketers.  :o)   (And I am one)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter that you wrap it in an H2.  It's semantically okay.  Here's what the W3C has to say about heading tags (H1 - H6)-

> A heading element briefly describes the topic of the section it introduces. Heading information may be used by user agents, for example, to construct a table of contents for a document automatically.

Your H2 is a subdescription of the H1.  ie: H1 describes the page subject, H2 describes the location.  Works okay in my mind.

Comment: This would create a wrong outline. The content that follows the `h2` (until the next `h2` or `h1` begins) would be in the scope of "/home/about/company/", which would be not correct.